# Openshift Python and Nodejs in the same app

Tags: python, django, node.js, openshift, bower

I am building a Django project and in Openshift I have an app with the cartridge for Python 2.7 and Mysql 5.5. I also want to use bower to manage the client side packages, but **bower** has as dependencies **npm** and **Node**. In Openshift, I've got npm installed, but I don't have Node, so I can't install bower.

How can I install Nodejs in openshift?

Note: I don't have sudo permission in openshift.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The host environment provides access to `npm` and `nodejs-0.6` - even if you've selected the python web service.

If you want to minimize your repo contents, and use OpenShift to run your builds remotely, I'd try using [`action_hooks`](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html#customizing-openshift-build-process) to provide your own custom build steps.

You could also consider running your builds locally, and committing and shipping your build results, possibly via an alternate "release" or "build" branch.